# extjs itemselector, how to load avialable and selected from store

Tags: extjs4

```
{
    xtype: 'itemselector',
    name: 'psa_id',
    id: 'psa_id',
    store: all_psa_store,
    displayField: 'refrence',
    valueField: 'mspa_id',
    **value: [23,56],
    //howtoloadthisfromstore**allowBlank: true,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    toTitle: '<fontcolor="blue">GAMSelected</font>',
    fromTitle: '<fontcolor="green">GAMAvailable</font>'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the afterrender event of your itemselector. In the callback load the store which holds the prioritized id's.

```
this.control({
    '#youritemselector' : {
        afterrender : this.reloadItemSelector
    }
});
```

...

```
reloadItemSelector: function(itemselector) {
    yourPriorityStore.load(function() {
        var selected = [];
        Ext.each(yourPriorityStore.data.items, function(item) {
            selected.push(item['data']['id']);
        });

        itemselector.setValue(selected);
    });
}
```